# Keep textfield above keyboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am trying to figure out how to keep the textfield about the keyboard in IOS. I tried the different code on stackoverflow but none works perfectly. Like if the textfield is above the keyboard and I click on the field, it does not move up. How can I show the textfield above the keyboard at all times? thanks!

Comment: will you please the sample code you tried?

Comment: does this help: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-keeping-content-from-underneath-the-keyboard/?

Answer (score 1):

lakesh's link is an excellent resource to look at.

There are essentially two ways to handle the situation.

*Method 1:*

You can encapsulate your view inside a `UIScrollView` and when the keyboard pops up, you should scroll your entire view up an equal distance to account for the space taken up by the keyboard.

*Method 2:*

Take the ultimate parent `UIView` inside your current `UIViewController` and change its frame (ideally with an animation) so that it moves off the top of the screen and makes way for the keyboard.

As a general guide, **Method 1 is the preferred method**. This is because you can still access the UI 'higher up' in the `UIScrollView` by scrolling up to it (consider say, a form with multiple fields). In Method 2 the user cannot return to the other elements in the view without the keyboard first being dismissed. Of course, it may be that you don't *need* to see the rest of the view while accepting keyboard input, but that decision is up to you.

Comment: For methods 1, you may adjust "contentInset" instead of "contentOffset". This makes better user experience.