# How can I Scroll TextField just above the keyboard?

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, flutter-layout, textfield

I have list of tasks and below that I have TextField, now when the multiple tasks added then I need to show TextField just above the keyboard.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Small piece of code :

```
    TextFormField(
      scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom - 160), // this line not work for me.
      cursorColor: Colors.black,
      toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(copy: true, cut: true, paste: true, selectAll: true),
      showCursor: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0 ? true : false,
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15.0,
        fontFamily: "Roboto",
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        color: darkGreyColor,
      ),
      controller: _textFieldControllerSubTaskAdd,
      focusNode: focusNodeSubTask,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      onChanged: (text) {
      },      
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: could you please add the code you have done so far?

Comment: Added code. pl check.

Comment: what I see in screen shot shows that you have two textfield, you want the one with red button stick to the top of keyboard when it is open? if yes, what about when keyboard close, could you please provide the image when keyboard close?

Comment: I have added another screenshot.

Comment: When I add subTask I want to keep it just above the keyboard.

Comment: maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736571/when-i-select-a-textfield-the-keyboard-moves-over-it) could help you.

Comment: [This link might help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372167/keep-textfield-above-keyboard) It looks the same as your problem.